# DUnit: How to run tests?

Tags: delphi, unit-testing, tdd, delphi-5, dunit

How do i run **TestCase**'s from the IDE?

i created a new project, with a single, simple, form:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms, Dialogs,
  StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
  private
  public
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.DFM}

end.
```

Now i'll add a test case to check that pushing `Button1` does what it should:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms, Dialogs,
  StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
     Button1: TButton;
     procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
  public
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.DFM}

uses
    TestFramework;

type
  TForm1Tests = class(TTestCase)
  private
        f: TForm1;
  protected
     procedure SetUp; override;
     procedure TearDown; override;
  published
     procedure TestButton1Click;
  end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
    //todo
end;

{ TForm1Tests }

procedure TForm1Tests.SetUp;
begin
  inherited;

    f := TForm1.Create(nil);
end;

procedure TForm1Tests.TearDown;
begin
    f.Free;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TForm1Tests.TestButton1Click;
begin
    f.Button1Click(nil);
    Self.CheckEqualsString('Hello, world!', f.Caption);
end;

end.
```

Given what i've done (test code in the GUI project), how do i now trigger a run of the tests? If i push <kbd>F9</kbd> then the form simply appears:

[image]

Ideally there would be a button, or menu option, in the IDE saying **Run DUnit Tests**:

[image]

Am i living in a dream-world? A fantasy land, living in a gumdrop house on lollipop lane?

Comment: As an aside, you'll find that your business logic is easier to unit test if you separate it out into classes, rather than trying to unit test your UI event handlers directly.

Comment: @Monk: The downside of that is that i have code spread across multiple classes, or worse multiple files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I agree with Uwe Raabe, but sometimes it can be useful to have a 'hidden' link within your app to run the DUnit GUI. I use:

```
TGUITestRunner.runRegisteredTests;
```

Call this from your button at the DUnit GUI will open for you to manually run and view test output.

---

For example, if you hold down a special key combination when opening the software's own *"Control Panel"*, you get some advanced entries:

[image]

Comment: WHy is this better than having a project group with MyApp and MyApp_Tests as two separate projects?

Comment: If i have a separate project with test code, then wouldn't have a separate project? i really don't want to have to flip between projects. i don't want to have to flip a drop-down between "Real Project" and "Test Project". If that means i have test code embedded in my final executable: then so be it.

Comment: A switchable 'real' and 'test' mode project? Code smells ahead :P

Comment: @Ian Boyd: Seems, there is the way to do it as desgined or the "lollipop lane".

Comment: @Uwe i'm more interested in ease of use, rather than how others use it.

Comment: @mjustin Your idea sounds interesting - one project. How would one do it?

Comment: @Warren P: Because there are (nasty) situtations where your app is on a customer's machine, he (She) is not looking over your shoulder and you bless that you can use some low-level built in tools such as your DUnit tests to assure you that the basics are ok. Bri

Comment: @Brian Frost: No one hinders you to copy the TextProject.exe to that machine and run it.

Comment: @Ian Boyd: I have done something like a "switchable" project for automating the screenshots. I use a special build configuration for that. It's like a debug build, the customer will (should) never see it.

Comment: +1 for being able to run your tests from within a production environment. @Uwe you might be allowed or able to copy your test executable into the production environment.

Comment: +1 for the idea too! There are many cases where it is annoying or problematic to get the customer to get another EXE and run it.

Comment: @Brian:  Your customer is lucky to have a developer working for them who understands the value of unit testing.   Isn't it ironic that when they have one of the good-ones (ie you), you get the runaround? :-)

Comment: @Uwe Raabe "No one hinders you to copy the TextProject.exe to that machine and run it." i have two government agencies hindering me from copying a `TestProject.exe`. The more i can jam into the one executable. i already embed a `IXMLHttpRequest` test app (when they have a proxy in the way), and a **Query Analyzer**. Running tests remotely over **CoPilot** is one more good thing.

Answer (score 12):

Adding a TestCase to the main project is not the way to go. You should create a separate TestProject (you can have it in the same ProjectGroup as the main project), add a TestCase and run.

Comment: Exactly. Test Case code does not belong IN YOUR APPLICATION.  Your test case project contains your unit tests. You create a new unit test application, you add your application code to the uses-clause of your unit test.

Comment: Is there a way to run the test project without having to switch away from the real project? i'd like to treat tests similar to a `Syntax Check`, `Build Project` or `Build All`.

Comment: add it as another project to the **same project group**. Then you can do a build all from here and so forth...

Comment: @François Is there a way to run the tests contained in the other "test project" while i'm in the project i'm developing?

Comment: Seems to me that people are concerned about test code being in the executable, rather than being logically separate - and used to test the code. i'm okay with DUnit working it so that the test cases are compiled away...

Comment: @Ian. Yes you can run run both projects in the debugger provided they have been both compiled before starting the 1st one.

Comment: And the reason i can't do this is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2508703/delphi-how-to-set-the-default-project-in-a-project-group

Answer (score 2):

I like the idea of having a `'Run DUnit tests'` command in the IDE.

It could be implemented by checking for a DUnit project in the same folder, having the same name as the current project:

- **Project1.dpr** -> the software under test
- **Project1.Tests.dpr** => the DUnit test app

In this case, the IDE should enable the Run DUnit tests command.

- After executing the tests, a list of all failed tests should be displayed which allows to jump to the source line where a test **failed**.
- If tests caused memory leaks, a list of all leaks should be displayed which allows to jump to the source line where **the memory leak has been created**

(DUnit can be configured to detect memory leaks and fail tests when one has been found)

Comment: Now someone just has to write it ;)

Comment: Maybe one of my supporters :) http://delphi.uservoice.com/forums/4432-general/suggestions/537663-dunit-ide-integration-for-failed-test